Using Files / Batch API through Azure Open AI Endpoint
This link provides the steps to access openai through Azure OpenAI with APIM. 
https://github.com/microsoft/AzureOpenAI-with-APIM/blob/main/example_code/example.py

Following is the code as given in the above link to use chat_completions API by OpenAI .
apim_url = "apim_url" deployment_name = "deployment_name" api_version = "2024-02-15-preview" subscription_key = "subscription_key"

url = f"{apim_url}/deployments/{deployment_name}/chat/completions?api-version={api_version}" headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key }

json_payload = { "messages": [ { "role": "system", "content": "You are an AI assistant that helps people find information." }, { "role": "user", "content": "What are the differences between Azure Machine Learning and Azure AI services?" } ], "temperature": 0.7, "top_p": 0.95, "max_tokens": 800 }

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_payload)

I want to use the Open AI files and Batch API  in this way . How can I do that ?

The Batch mode provided by OpenAI (see doc) does not exist / is not available in Azure OpenAI - at least for the moment.
So if the APIM encapsulates an Azure OpenAI endpoint (not an OpenAI endpoint), you cannot achieve what you want as the underlying API (Azure OpenAI API) does not provide batch operations.
